# My WP_Query won't return more than 9 items

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-gutenberg

I have created a wordpress query to return all the "products" but it only returns 9. (weird number, I know). I have a total of 13 custom posts for "products". I have added `post_per_page = -1` and `post_per_page = 20`. Both have not made a difference.

Here is my loop. Is there a way to debug it to see how it's breaking? Or does anyone know why it's breaking? Thank you

```
                    <?php
                    // WP_Query arguments
                    $args = array(
                        'p'                      => 'products',
                        'post_type'              => array( 'products' ),
                        'order'                  => 'ASC',
                        'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
                        'meta_key'  => 'custom_product_position',
                        'post_per_page' => 20,
                    );

                    // The Query
                    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    // The Loop
                    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                            $query->the_post();
                            $product_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_product_title', true );
                            $product_subtitle = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_product_subtitle', true );
                            $product_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_product_id', true );



                            ?>
                            <div id="<?php if ( ! empty( $product_id ) ) {echo $product_id;}?>" class="section-title">
                                <?php
                                if ( ! empty( $product_title ) ) {
                                    echo "<h2>" . $product_title . "</h2>";
                                }
                                ?>
                                <?php
                                if ( ! empty( $product_subtitle ) ) {
                                    echo "<h4>" . $product_subtitle . "</h4>";
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            echo get_the_content();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // no posts found
                    }

                    // Restore original Post Data
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also the limit that you set within the WP settings for the maximum amount of posts displayed on post loops in general ("Settings > Read"). Try to increase that - should work...

Comment: Thanks this worked! I was looking on the PHP side, but it was simply in the actual wordpress settings. This saved me a headache!